# Last digit of $2^{9^{100}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If the last digit of $9^{9^9}$ is $z$  then find the last digit of $2^{z^{100}}$.
**My try:-**
As  unit digit of $9^{\text{odd}}$ is $9$, then $z=9$. Then we are asked to find the last digit of $2^{9^{100}}$. 
I'm unable to find it. Please help me.

Comment: $2^{1} = \color{#f00}{2}\,\quad 2^{2} = 4\quad 2^{3} = 8\quad 2^{4} = 16\quad 2^{5} = 3\color{#f00}{2}$.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1491279/11619)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$9 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ so for any $k$, $9^k \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.

Also, $2^{4s+1}$ ends in a $2$.

So the answer is the last digit of 
$$2^{9^{100}}$$
is $2$.

Comment: At this level, you should probably say more about *why* $\, 2^{4N+1}\!\equiv 2\pmod{10}\ $ for all $\,N,\ $ since that is the crux of the matter.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the units digit of $2^n$ goes through a cycle $2,4,8,6$, so you just need $n \bmod 4$ to figure out the units digit.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

$$\text{Euler's formula:  }\quad a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod{n} \text{ when} \gcd(a,n)=1$$

$$\phi(10)=\phi(2)\phi(5)=4$$

$$a^4\equiv 1 \pmod {10}$$

Therefore:

$$\color{green}{9^{100}}\equiv (9^{25})^4\equiv \color{red}1\pmod{10}$$

$$2^{\color{green}{9^{100}}}\equiv 2^\color{red}1\equiv 2\pmod {10}$$